# What does Use Case and Interactor mean in the context of clean architecture?

Tags: android, mvp, use-case, clean-architecture

What is Use Case and Interactor in context of Clean Architecture. I read that use case contains business logic, but why use case if there is a presentation layer where in presenter we can put business logic.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/why-you-need-use-cases-interactors-142e8a6fe576

Answer (score 8):

In Clean Architecture "use case" and "interactor" means the same: it is the component which contains business logic. The presenter in this architecture does not contain any business logic. The job of the presenter is to map data structures returned by the use case interactor into data structures most convenient for the view.

Answer (score 3):

"Use Case" is a term that, to my knowledge, was coined or at least formalized by computing pioneer Ivar Jacobson. It is a concept the stresses a particular view on the system, namely a user-centric view, i.e. he asks, what does the user want to achieve with a system? One interaction of one user with one system end-to-end is a use case.

I haven't heard the term "Interactor" in this context but maybe it's just what Jacobson calls the "Actor." The words are similar enough.

Let's say you want to transfer money. You open the transfer web page, enter the amount, select the beneficiary or enter a new one, you provide a one-time password, and you see that your transfer is in progress. This is one use case.

Use cases can have multiple scenarios. In the example, what happens if you don't have the required funds? What happens if your beneficiary information fails to validate? What happens if you enter the one-time password incorrectly several times? What happens if you try to transfer a very large amount or many small amounts in a short time?

Also, use cases can have preconditions, e.g. you have to be already authenticated to even begin with the money transfer use case. The authentication would be specified elsewhere and just documented as a precondition, to keep things neat and tidy. Post-conditions can also specify the state of the system after the use case is complete.

And finally, the actor performing the use case might not be a person at all--it could be another system.

Recently, I've heard the term "customer journey" that seems to mean the same or at least a similar concept.

Bottom line: "Use case" is not a term that is in any way specific to the implementation of a system. Rather, use cases are used to look at a system from the outside and describe its behavior from a user point of view.

Answer (score 0):

A use case is a methodology used in system analysis to identify, clarify, and organize system requirements. The use case is made up of a set of possible sequences of interactions between systems and users in a particular environment and related to a particular goal. It consists of a group of elements (for example, classes and interfaces) that can be used together in a way that will have an effect larger than the sum of the separate elements combined. The use case should contain all system activities that have significance to the users. A use case can be thought of as a collection of possible scenarios related to a particular goal, indeed, the use case and goal are sometimes considered to be synonymous.

A use case (or set of use cases) has these characteristics:

- Organizes functional requirements
- Models the goals of system/actor (user) interactions
- Records paths (called scenarios) from trigger events to goals
- Describes one main flow of events (also called a basic course of
  action), and possibly other ones, called exceptional flows of events
  (also called alternate courses of action)
- Is multi-level, so that one use case can use the functionality of
  another one.

Use cases can be employed during several stages of software    development, such as planning system requirements, validating design,    testing software, and creating an outline for online help and user    manuals.

Comment: This doesn't answer what a use case is _in the context of Clean Architecture_